# Antenna for WiFi card to boost WiFi signal

Tags: desktop, wifi

I have desktop computer with [Asus WiFi PCI card: PCE N10](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEN10/).

It loads Web pages much slower than other computers in my apartment, probably because it is placed on the floor under the desk, with WiFi antenna on the back directed to a metal radiator.

The current antenna can be detached from the WiFi card.

I am looking for a 2.4GHz antenna that:

- can be connected to the existing card
- has a cable, so it can be placed above the desk while the PC remains under
- boosts WiFi signal maximally
- costs less than 40$

Comment: Regards the antenna, you can get antennas with a desktop (usually magnetic too) base, with a "pigtail" cable such as this https://www.amazon.com/Insten-335802-Booster-Antenna-Wireless/dp/B004I1GHKY/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1508319307&sr=1-1&keywords=magnetic+antenna+pigtail

Comment: Your question as it is right now may be off-topic since you aren't asking for a specific piece of hardware, rather you're asking how to troubleshoot an issue before a recommendation can be given for a a piece of hardware.  The short answer to both your questions is Yes.  The question you need to ask, "Can someone recommend me a solution to the problem (either an antenna extension or new wifi card)?"  This is what your title suggests, but the body of your question doesn't.  We also don't have enough details about your needs.  Budget, for example.